# Finding the biggest segment in array such that minimum value in it is greater or equal the segment's size

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

I'm trying to do the following task in O(n) complexity:

```
Given an array [|x_1,x_2,...,x_n|] return the biggest s such that there exists 
a segment of length s - [|x_i,x_(i+1),...,x_j|], in which the minimum value 
is greater or equal (j-i+1).
```

UPDATE:
There was an incorrect O(n) solution right here and I managed to code up the correct (at least I think so), simple O(n*log n) one. Here it is:

```
let segment a = 
    let n = Array.length a in
    let pointer_1 = ref 0 in
    let pointer_2 = ref 0 in
    let q = ref (put empty_queue (a.(0), 0)) in
    let best = ref 0 in
    begin
        while (!pointer_2 < n) do
            let size = (!pointer_2 - !pointer_1 + 1) in
            q := put !q (a.(!pointer_2), !pointer_2);
            let ((lmin, pmin), qright) = getmin !q in
            if (size > lmin) then begin
                best := max !best (size-1);
                pointer_1 := pmin + 1;
                pointer_2 := !pointer_2 + 1;
                q := qright
            end
            else
                begin
                    best := max !best (size);
                    pointer_2 := !pointer_2 + 1
                end
        done;
        !best
    end;;
```

Where q is a reference to a priority queue which returns minimum elements first. Still, can this be done in O(n) in a simple way?

Comment: You want to find the biggest segment, in which the minimum value is less than or equal to the segment size? Let me know if I miss something, but wouldn't this segment - if it exists - be the entire array always?

Comment: No, for example in [|1;2;3;4;5;6|] the biggest segments are [|3;4;5|] and [|4;5;6|] (note that in the second example we could throw another number if it existed and was >= 4, because min of that segment is 4)

Comment: But [|4;5;6|] doesn't follow the definition. The minimum value (4) is greater than the segment size (3). Unless you meant the minimum value must be larger than the segment size. Then it would make sense.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for misleading title and description. I meant "greater" of course

Comment: Are all the numbers consecutive ? I mean x_(I+k) = x_i + k ?

Comment: No, it was just an example

Comment: Your explanation doesn't type check: you are subtracting an array from something and calling it a length?

Comment: Another nitpick: couldn't you start with `pointer_2`:= ref 1` since you are storing the first array element in the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice little puzzle! Here is a solution based on a double-ended queue.

My algorithm is mostly the same as yours, except that I use the dequeue to keep track of the minimum values: the queue contains an increasing sequence of values: the first one is the minimum of the current interval, the second one is the minimum of the sub-interval that starts after the first minimum, and so on.

When I advance the left pointer past the minimum value, I remove this value from the left of the queue, and the rest of the queue naturally starts with the minimum of the remaining interval.

When I advance the right pointer, I check the new value against the right of the queue. If the new value is smaller, I remove the right-most entry and check again with the remaining queue. When all bigger values are removed I can add the new value at the end of the dequeue.

I had to add a special case when a nonpositive value is found in the array: advance both pointers at the same time.

Beware: I'm using (and returning) semi-open intervals because they are much less error-prone than closed intervals.

This code is only lightly tested. To show that it's O(n), note that each value is entered at most once in the dequeue.

```
let segment a =
  let len = Array.length a in
  let p1 = ref 0 in
  let p2 = ref 0 in
  let bestlen = ref 0 in
  let best = ref [(0,0)] in
  let q = Dq.make len in
  while !p2 < len do
    let l = !p2 - !p1 in
    if (Dq.is_empty q || Dq.peek_left q > l) && a.(!p2) > l
    then begin
      while not (Dq.is_empty q) && Dq.peek_right q > a.(!p2) do
        Dq.pop_right q;
      done;
      Dq.push_right q a.(!p2);
      incr p2;
    end else if !p1 < !p2 then begin
      if a.(!p1) = Dq.peek_left q then Dq.pop_left q;
      incr p1;
    end else begin
      assert (Dq.is_empty q);
      incr p1;
      incr p2;
    end;
    let l = !p2 - !p1 in
    if l > !bestlen then begin
      bestlen := l;
      best := [];
    end;
    if l = !bestlen then best := (!p1, !p2) :: !best;
  done;
  !best
;;
```

Here is a bare-bones implementation of a double-ended queue, rather specific to the above code:

```
module Dq = struct
  type t = {
    mutable hd : int;
    data : int array;
    mutable tl : int;
  }
  let make len = {
    hd = 0;
    data = Array.make len 0;
    tl = 0;
  };;
  let push_right q x =
    assert (q.tl < Array.length q.data);
    q.data.(q.tl) <- x;
    q.tl <- q.tl + 1;
  ;;
  let is_empty q = q.tl = q.hd;;
  let peek_right q =
    assert (q.hd < q.tl);
    q.data.(q.tl - 1)
  ;;
  let peek_left q =
    assert (q.hd < q.tl);
    q.data.(q.hd)
  ;;
  let pop_left q =
    assert (q.hd < q.tl);
    q.hd <- q.hd + 1;
  ;;
  let pop_right q =
    assert (q.hd < q.tl);
    q.tl <- q.tl - 1;
  ;;
end
```